# How do I define custom comparison (0 < mytype) in python?

Tags: python

So I'm currently (ab)using python notation to create a domain specific language. As part of this I'm overriding comparison functions to return non-boolean values.

So, for (mytype1 < mytype2) and (mytype < 0) I can easily do this by defining the __lt__() magic method.

However, I cannot figure out how to do so for (0 < mytype) as presumably the magic method would need to be defined on the built-in int type. There doesn't seem to be a __rlt__() function as exists for numeric operations.

How do I add support for this comparison where the lhs is of type int (in python3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) the reflected form of `__lt__()` is `__gt__()`.

> There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods (to be used when the left argument does not support the operation but the right argument does); rather, `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` are each other’s reflection, `__le__()` and `__ge__()` are each other’s reflection, and `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` are their own reflection. If the operands are of different types, and right operand’s type is a direct or indirect subclass of the left operand’s type, the reflected method of the right operand has priority, otherwise the left operand’s method has priority. Virtual subclassing is not considered.

Comment: Thanks - I swear that wasn't there when I read that section before posting!